# Handle javax.el.ELException

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss7.x

I'm trying to handle a `javax.el.ELException` which happens from within an `AJAX` update. Those get thrown for example when an exception occurs in a bound getter through an EL expression. I have a custom ExceptionHandler in place but it never receives the exception. I also tried the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` of Omnifaces, but this one wasn't able to process it either.

What happens now is that the page is rendered only partly in the browser to the point where the exception happened.

To me it looks like JBoss is already handling this exception, since it produces a log line with only the message of the exception inside.

I want to be able to send the browser to a default error page whenever an exception occurs in an `AJAX` update.

Comment: Have you tried something like this <error-page>
     <exception-type>javax.el.ELException</exception-type>
     <location>/errorPage.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>

Comment: *"but this one wasn't able to process it either"* please be more specific. It by defaults unwraps the root cause from `FacesException` or `ELException`, because those are basically wrapper exceptions, so that ultimately the real root cause of EL exception can be specifically handled (e.g. `NullPointerException` or so).

Comment: @BalusC As a test I raised a RuntimeException myself in one of my getters. So this was the 'root cause'.

Comment: @Srikanth That only works fine for non-ajax updates.

Comment: *"but this one wasn't able to process it either"* please be more specific. What exactly do you see in log? Didn't you just see *"An exception occurred during rendering JSF ajax response. Error page '/blabla.xhtml' CANNOT be shown as response is already committed. Consider increasing 'javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE' if it really needs to be handled."* which is already the whole answer at its own.

Comment: @BalusC The log shows completely nothing, except the logging of JSF which shows the message of the exception. I don't get the '... is already committed' message either. I already tried to put the buffer size MUCH higher, but that doesn't solve anything either. I already read that in one of your other answers.

Comment: Okay, rephrased, your concrete problem is thus that the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` isn't being invoked at all? This problem description is namely completely different from "wasn't able to process it". If you even can't tell this for sure, just put a debug breakpoint on `handle()` method to see if it's actually hit.

Comment: Maybe let me put it in this way: I first made a custom `ExceptionHandler` myself. This one was triggered without a single problem. The problem is that the queue of unhandled exceptions does not contain the exceptions we are talking about. It does sometimes contains others. So I /think/ the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` will be triggered just fine but it won't see the exception on the queue either. I will try to put a breakpoint in there soon to confirm this behaviour 100% sure.

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I did further investigation. This is what I see in the logging:
09:01:16,043 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-6) javax.el.ELException: /my_page.xhtml @34,75 value="#{myBean.myProperty}": java.lang.RuntimeException: blabla. 
The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` gets called just fine, but `!unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents.hasNext()` returns `false`. So it seems like the exception doesn't get on the queue.

Comment: Okay. Do you have more exception handlers in your webapp?

Comment: @BalusC In the `faces-config.xml` is only the `FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory` now.